# Paragon app won't mount

Tags: usb-drivers

I have a Galaxy Note 2014 edition. I rooted the device in order to use a NTFS partitioned external HD. I followed all the instructions, used the root checker and everything is fine. When I connect the external drive it is recognized by Paragon but when I click "mount" it just flashes back to the initial screen of the app.
Does anybody have a clue of what is possibly going wrong?
(I've tried other apps such as stickmount, ntfs mounter and none of them worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In paragon mount, try changing the mount point when you tap mount. Just make a new folder in the root of your storage space.